# Can't execute a java code from command line

Tags: java, command-line

Hello my jdk is well installed in:D:\java on my computer
my path is :
D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;D:\java\bin;D:\jboss-as-7.1.3.Final\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;E:\formation\Essais\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.0-bin\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin

my Java_Home :D:\java
my little program is in :E:\Zoo.java

my program is completely:

```
public class Zoo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

in the command prompt i type this : javac Zoo.java

I don't get "Hello": please will like to know why and  what to do

Comment: javac compiles your code, it doesn't run the compiled code. You should now have a Zoo.class in that same directory. If so, run `java Zoo` and it'll work.

Comment: Please read some tutorials. javac compiles the code it doesnot run the code

Comment: Thanks very much.... I works

Comment: Please is ther a way to complie and run it at once?

Comment: @Bizi no, *Java is both compiled and interpreted.*

Comment: Thanks I know that therorically, thanks for your help

Comment: Java 9 will let you do that, but for now, the answer is no. Of course, it wouldn't be hard to write a little script that you'd run as `javarun Foo` and just does `javac Foo.java && java Foo`.

Comment: thakns for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compile it with `javac Zoo.java` and run it with `java Zoo`. From the comments :-

> Please is there a way to compile and run it at once?

**No**, Java is both compiled and interpreted.